# iOS Simulator and backend performance

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, ios-simulator, database-performance

I have been creating a chat app and recently came across a few issues.
When I log in, the initial VC is one made of the added users. I can tap on any of them to start a new conversation. My backend is Parse and I store my messages and info there.

The problem is that when I tap on the user the messages take too long to load. Is that related to the server or to the simulator itself? I went to the server and I got no slow queries..

Also, the app itself responds kind of slowly. When I type on the "Type message" view the keyboard takes some time to appear, it is not immediate and this does not depend on the server.
I even tried running the app on my actual iPhone and it is still pretty laggy and crashes from time to time.

Is this normal on the development process or should I expect my app to perform better and in real time when I test it on my real iPhone?

Comment: It is impossible to say - you could have a slow network connection or terrible code; you haven't shown any. You can use the instruments tool to analyse the performance of your app and identify poorly performing blocks of code.  The fact that you get occasional crashes indicates that you certainly have some problems in your code

Comment: the internet connection is a fast one. I will try to use the instruments tool, wasn't aware of that. Is it possible that a simple keyboardwillappear function is badly written and can slow the process? isn't the function used lots of times?

the simple clicks are slow

Comment: Slow performance is often related to performing network tasks on the main thread - you should use the ...inBackgroundWithBlock forms of the Parse methods or attempting to update the UI on a background thread.  Without seeing some code it is just guesses

Comment: This is a stretch, but if things are in mating slowly, make sure you don't have "slow animation" turned on in Simulator. I believe the short is 'cmd-T"

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I could not upload more information because i do not know where the problem is located. I will look into your suggestions and try to figure this out! Hopefully it gets on the right track!